# How does master secret calculates in encryption protocol used by WhatsApp?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, whatsapp

I have read the algorithm behind WhatsApp encryption in this [document](https://cryptome.org/2016/04/whatsapp-crypto.pdf). I can not understand how the initiator calculates a master secret.

> The initiator calculates a master secret as:
>
> ```
> master_secret = ECDH(Iinitiator, Srecipient) || ECDH(Einitiator, Irecipient) || ECDH(Einitiator, Srecipient) || ECDH(Einitiator, Orecipient).
> ```
>
> If there is no One Time Pre Key, the final `ECDH` is omitted.

Comment: I've read that paper twice and it is so hard to understand it. I hope someone here can explain it in layman's term.

Comment: WhatsApp uses the Signal protocol, you should read the [Signal protocol docs](https://signal.org/docs/).

Answer (score 2):

The `ECDH()` refers to *Elliptic-curve Diffie–Hellman*. It's mentioned in the paper only indirectly by referring to the *Signal Protocol* by Open Whisper Systems and *Curve25519*. This is a commercially focused white paper, so it does't really intend to get into the mathematics.

The reason for using 3–4 different Diffie–Hellman key pairs and concatenating (`||`) the operations is to prevent stolen private keys to be used to decrypt any previously captured communication: medium-term and one-time keys have changed during the time, while the long-term key pair proves it's still the same person. Because all these keys are needed, it also gives *plausible deniability*; any proofs of authenticity of the decrypted messages gets lost when the conversation finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Quick recap.

**Parameters generated by the initiator**:

1) **Iinitiator**, Identity Key (keypair) of the initiator;

2) **Einitiator**, an ephemeral (ie temporary) elliptic curve keypair.

**Parameters generated by the recipient**:

3) **Irecipient**, the recipient's identity key (keypair);

4) **Srecipient**, the recipient's signed pre key (keypair);

5) **Orecipient**, the recipient's one-time pre-key (keypair).

---

ECDH(Ka, Kb) is the [Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman) procedure between two parties, A with a keypair Ka and B with a keypair Kb.

|| is the concatenation operator.

The formula

```
 master_secret = ECDH(Iinitiator, Srecipient) || ECDH(Einitiator, Irecipient) || ECDH(Einitiator, Srecipient) || ECDH(Einitiator, Orecipient)
```

means that the ECDH protocol is run four times, using as keypairs:

1) Iinitiator and Srecipient;

2) Einitiator and Irecipient;

3) Einitiator and Srecipient;

4) Einitiator and Orecipient,

respectively. As you can see, each time two keypairs, each of which belongs to a different party, are used, which means all those `ECDH(. , .)` operations are valid.

Each of this operation generates a shared secret without directly revealing it to anyone else listening on the channel, thanks to the properties of the Diffie-Hellman protocol.

The results are concatenated, thus forming the master secret.